# Prevent Sublime Text sidebar from taking keyboard focus

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

I recently upgraded to Sublime Text 4. One change is that whenever I click in the sidebar, it takes over keyboard focus. After that I have to click back in an editor pane to give it focus again.

As far as I can tell, Sublime Text 3 didn't do that and I don't recall every having to configure that. I don't find it useful for the sidebar to ever have keyboard focus. Is there a way to turn it off so that clicking the sidebar does *not* give it keyboard focus?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this behavior only occurs when you click on the *currently focused file* in the sidebar. Clicking on any other file, whether it's currently open or not, switches the focus to that file. There is no documented setting or API function controlling this.

If this does happen, you can resume focus of the tab group that was previously focused by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + the number of the group (1-indexed) your file is in. So, for example, if you have 2 tab groups open and the file you were working on is in group 2, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>. If the window isn't split (so there's just one group), hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: > Please note that this behavior only occurs when you click on the currently focused file in the sidebar.

Oh, that's interesting. I hadn't noticed that but you're right.